# Remove white area in the page

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I'm working on that has a white area whenever the screen is larger than the page in terms of height `http://kauaiyogaandfitness.com/vid-page/`.

In that page I purposely remove contents just to highlight the problem.

What I want is to **FIT** the background image from top to bottom/left to right in all screen resolution/ratio.

I've tried to fix the problem using **100vh css** BUT when the screen is smaller than the contents, page won't let me scroll the page to see the hidden part of the content.

```
.et_pb_section_0 {
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm beginner.

Comment: Read [ask] and [edit] your question to follow those guidelines. Specifically, include an MCVE, instead of linking to known spam. Basically, what I'm saying is that seems to be a thinly-veiled attempt at spam, and if you don't want this question to get downvoted and possibly deleted for that, you should [edit] it to comply with everything in [ask].

Comment: Don't forget to include in your question the CSS you think is the problem. This helps explain the situation in technical terms and can provide context for people to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: First of all, thank you for making this topic more sense than I usually thought it was. But my statement above states what the problem is, and what I expect it to behave.  I have no time at the moment reading how I should post things here for time sake. Post will be deleted

Comment: Hope that addressed the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-height` instead of `height` so that the page will be *at least* 100vh, and will grow beyond that height if needed.

```
.et_pb_section_0 {
    background-image: url(http://kauaiyogaandfitness.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/1920x1080_3.jpg);
    min-height: 100vh; /* <---- add this */
}
```